# React Native - What is and isn't possible with React Native?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, react-native

I'm a web developer and have been playing around with React Native for a few days now and slowly getting the hang of how things work. I want to build a project but I don't even know if it's possible at this point? One side of my question pertains to the UI elements. I see a lot of native (Obj-C and Swift) apps doing this parallax hero space thing:

Example: https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader

Is something like that possible in React Native? If so, how? From what I understand, doing something like this requires the UiTableView, which RN does not have.

Secondly, I want to use some native things like the Map View. I've seen the notes on using RCTBridgeModule, but since I have zero experience with Obj-C, I dont know what they mean when they say to place this obj-c code [here] and then place this js [here].

The examples FB has provided are great for learning how to display content from an api, but when it comes to integrating with obj-c, it becomes a little fuzzy due to the lack of obj-c experience and the file structure related to it.

Am I the only one experiencing this? This seems like a great framework and I am very excited to learn it, but there still seems to be a void for the obj-c noobs.

Comment: I think you're question is too broad. You say you don't know Obj-C so if were to say "you can't use dispatch mechanism xyz" it wouldn't much sense anyway. Ultimately if you want to do anything advanced with RN you will still need to use Obj-C.

Comment: The framework is still in its early days with new features and libraries appearing every day, as this goes on expect the documentation and features to mature ... Until then you have to sort of make do with what's available, there are tutorials however people have written about making custom components http://moduscreate.com/react_native_custom_components_ios/

Answer (score 1):

I think this library is right for you first - [react-native-image-header-scroll-view](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-header-scroll-view)

You have 3 ways to use native modules.

1. If you use expo, it's pretty simple, they have their own collection of libraries to work with native modules that are easy to install. [Documentation is here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/accelerometer/)
2. If the expo doesn't suit you, you can still use Expo's library collection by installing [react-native-unimodules](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/). But you can also use any other third-party libraries to work with the modules. In this option, installing and setting up some libraries will additionally require recordings in the ios and android configurations.
3. You can write your own implementation of the logic of working with native modules on java or object-c and link it all to react-native.

Answer (score 0):

For functionalities, like the parallax link you sent, the best thing to do is check out the `react-native` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react-native) repository. (The [parallax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-parallax-view) example)